# bootstrap-flip-card-with-css3-transform is not working properly in IE

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

when i click on the front div, back div has to be flip. but here the issue is when i click on front div, it is flipped and reverse view of the front div is displaying. back div is not displaying. I could not able to find the issue why it is behaving like this.

Code:-

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/bootstrap.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <style>
        .flip {
            -webkit-perspective: 800;
            perspective: 800;

            position: relative;

        }
        .flip .card.flipped {
            -webkit-transform: rotatex(-180deg);
            transform: rotatex(-180deg);
        }
        .flip .card {

            height: 100%;
            -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
            -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
            transform-style: preserve-3d;
            transition: 0.5s;
        }
        .flip .card .face {

            -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden ;
            backface-visibility: hidden ;
            z-index: 2;

        }
        .flip .card .front {
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            z-index: 1;

        }
        .flip .card .back {
            -webkit-transform: rotatex(-180deg);
            transform: rotatex(-180deg);
        }
        .inner{margin:0px !important;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Flip view -->
    <div class="flip">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="face front">
                <div class="well well-sm inner"> Front</div>
            </div>
            <div class="face back">
                <div class="well well-sm inner"> Back</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<script>
    $('.flip').click(function(){
        $(this).find('.card').toggleClass('flipped');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Seems to work fine for me - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZpJXYX. Try moving the script before the </body> tag.

Comment: All browsers , the above code is working except IEedge. How to resolve it.